# Mapping an array in Knockout

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here's what I have mocked out of my MVC code:

```
$(function(){

    var ViewModel = function(){
      this.items = ko.observableArray(null);
      this.isLoading = ko.observable(true);  
    };

    var data = [{"CreatedAt":"2013-12-29T22:00:20","Intro":"","Body":"","Title":"Test Item","Url":"/news-items/test-item/"},{"CreatedAt":"2013-12-29T21:13:34","Intro":"","Body":"","Title":"Test 1","Url":"/news-items/test-1/"},{"CreatedAt":"2013-12-29T16:03:56","Intro":"","Body":"<p>In the spirit of Christmas we are holding a Christmas photo competition for all members to enter. Prizes will be given to the best Christmas themed photo and the funniest photo.&nbsp; To enter, simply email your photo to: competition@bernese.org.nz. Your entry will be uploaded onto the club's Facebook page where all members can then vote by 'liking' their favourite photo.</p>\n<p>Entries close on the 20th of December and voting will be open until the 5th of January. The winning photo's will be displayed on the website.</p>","Title":"Christmas 2013 Photo Competition","Url":"/news-items/christmas-2013-photo-competition/"}];
  var vm = new ViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
  vm.items(test);
  vm.isLoading(false);
})
```

I have mocked it from my MVC code, but the `data` object is basically what was returned from my controller. Knockout mapping is not working in this case and I suspect it's the way my data is returned. Is this a valid way, or do I need to wrap it in a DTO of sorts, e.g.: `{ items: [{item1:'...'},{item2:'...'}]}`?

Thanks.

EDIT:
My mistake, I already defined `items` as `observableArray`. I use it this way so as soon as the page loads the loader gif is displayed. I have done it this way before, the only difference this time being the format of the json returned.

ADDED: Here's the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/u54mn/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ko.mapping.fromJS(data)` returns a `ko.observableArray` if the `data` parameter is already an array.

So you need to unwrap the returned `ko.observableArray` before assigning it:

```
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
var test = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
vm.items(test()); // you need to write `test()` to get the underlaying array.
```

Or you can directly fill in your already declared `ko.observableArray` with writing:

```
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {} /* mapping options */, vm.items);
```

Here is your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9F6x/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the only problem, but

```
this.items = ko.observable(null);
```

should be

```
this.items = ko.observableArray();
```

But I probably do the whole thing more like

```
$(function(){
    var ViewModel = function(items){
        this.items = ko.observableArray(items);  
    };

    var data = [...];
    var vm = new ViewModel(data);
})
```

UPDATE: [Here is a fully working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u54mn/12/)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this too and it's not working either. It seems the output of `ko.mapping.fromJS(data)` is correct, so I must be missing something fundamental here. This is my latest example: http://jsfiddle.net/u54mn/10/

Comment: I updated my answer with a working jsfiddle. The main problem was mapping the observableArray twice - you don't need to because fromJS returns an observable array for you.